# Copy files to System32 on 64bit OS

Tags: wix

I am creating an msi. I need to copy one file to System32 folder irrespective of OS architecture. When using `SystemFolder` property it appears on `SysWOW64` folder in x64. can I use [System64Folder](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa372054(v=vs.85).aspx) and [SystemFolder](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa372055(v=vs.85).aspx) in the same msi or is there any other ways to do this.

Comment: And if your using `SystemFolder` you get '''C:\Windows\System32''' even on a 64bit OS, don't you? That's the same on a 32bit OS.

Comment: `SysWOW64` *is* for 32b files

Comment: @harper no. When using SystemFolder I get SysWOW64. in 32 bit os I get System32.

I need t copy file to C:\Windows\System32 even in x64 os

Comment: You think a 32bit OS _has_ a `SysWOW64` folder? I doubt it.

Comment: @harper You misunderstood me. When I install on a 64 bit os I need to copy my files to System32 instead of SysWOW64. In 32 bit OS it copies to System32, ie working correctly.

Comment: 32 bit processes get their SystemFolder redirected to SysWOW64 just like how 32 bit processes get their HKLM\SOFTWARE\ registry redirected to HLKM\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\. Wix has explicit `Win64` tags for several components which force the 64-bit locations to be used on a 32bit process installation.

Comment: My previous comment may be incorrect regarding File paths for components marked Win64, will need to write a test program to figure out the real answer. Win64="yes" does force registry searches and keys to go into the 64-bit registry locations if they are present though. I've done that in a few installations.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A 32-bit MSI can't install files to native 64-bit system folders. It will redirect to the 32-bit WoW64 folder, and in a verbose log you'll see WIN64DUALFOLDERS redirection. As the docs say here:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa367451(v=vs.85).aspx

a 32-bit MSI can contain only 32-bit components. So you can't have 64-bit components in a 32-bit install that will install your file to the native 64-bit folder.

Different setups are required for different architectures:

https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/heaths/2008/01/15/different-packages-are-required-for-different-processor-architectures/

so one solution would be a WiX Burn bundle that includes a 64-bit setup to install that file.

Comment: I've never tried to put something in the 64bit system folder from a 32bit install since I've seen the bad behaviour that can happen if 3rd party library dlls are in there and the dll load order finds that one first. I assumed the Win64 tags on a component would work like the Win64 tags in registry related elements.

Answer (score 3):

Mark the components which need to go into the "System32" folder on a 64-bit machine as explicitly 64 bit and condition them around that fact.

```
<Component Id="IAmA64BitBinary" Win64="yes" Directory="SystemFolder">
  <Condition>VersionNT64</Condition>
  <File Id="IAmTheBinary" KeyPath="yes" Source="file.dll">
</Component>
```

The "Win64="yes"" indicates that this is referring to the 64-bit SystemFolder and the condition ensures this components only installs on a 64-bit machine where this system folder actually exists.

I'm not 100% sure if the condition is required but it doesn't hurt I guess. If you are requiring some 64-bit components I would suggest you have a launch condition added to your installtion

```
<Comdition message="Must install on a 64-bit OS">VersionNT64</Condition>
```

(also to note; we don't need to add "OR Installed" to this launch condition since the VersionNT64 property can't change between installing and uninstalling/upgrading.)